# How do you integrate Google map API key?

Tags: maps

I have an issue with google map API key, which is perfectly working when we are using this key in india ( with accurate locations ) but when it comes to Kenya it doesn’t. Though the Key is generated with Kenya’s account.
What might be the issue?
Thanks